# Using Gii with SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2008, yii2, gii

I have two DB within my Yii2 Application. I'm trying to use Gii to generate models for SQL-Server 2008. But I keep getting:

`Connection does not support reading schema information for 'sqlsrv' DBMS.`

I am able to connect to the DB and pull data and use it within my application though, is Gii not available for use with SQL-Server 2008?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked into my connection and had mapped my Schema, perhaps incorrectly.

When I removed this from the config it worked:

```
'schemaMap' => [
  'mssql'=> [
    'class'=>'yii\db\mssql\Schema',
    'defaultSchema' => 'dbo'
  ]
],
```